# how to set keep check radio button after refresh page or after change value in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hello i want to keep my radio button checked with previous value after refresh page i have also set variable value in controller but it is not working correct. here my html and angular code

```
<script>app.controller('commonController', ['$scope', 'httpMethodService', '$rootScope', 'growl', 'helperService', 'userService', '$auth','$routeParams',
function ($scope, httpMethodService, $rootScope, growl, helperService, userService, $auth,$routeParams,$routeProvider) {

 $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
     if($routeParams.result == 'mlb'){

         $scope.result == '1';
     }else{

         $scope.result == '2';
     }
        // $routeParams should be populated here
      });


    helperService.checkSubscribed();
    $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
    if (userService.checkExistKey('u_id')) {
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
    } else {
        console.log("not-login");
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
    }
    $scope.$watch('isLoggedIn', function () {
        helperService.checkSubscribed();
    });

    $scope.authenticate = function (provider) {
        $auth.authenticate(provider);
    };
}]);</script>
```

here my HMTL

```
    <div ng-init="submitResult(result);"  class = "headerradio">

                        <lable>Choose a game- :</lable>
                        <input type="radio" ng-model='result'ng-click="submitResult(result);clearSearchParam();"  ng-value='"1"' name="rdoResult">MLB
                        <input type="radio" ng-model='result' ng-click="submitResult(result);clearSearchParam();" ng-value='"2"' name="rdoResult">NFL

  </div>
```

first controller will load so i am setting up value using $routParams and setting result value. but this code is not working.

Comment: you need localStorage

Comment: can't i set value based on my url value using $routParams object i am getting also value actually these radio button click event also change value in url so i think to get value of url and set the radio property

Comment: as @brk said, i would use localStorage

Comment: @brk you are right i just used localStorage and done this. thank for telling me about it.

Comment: @ShaktiSisodiya happy to help